# wordnet similarity calculation in python

Tags: python, wordnet

I have list of *medical words in a file*. I have a list of tweets which are *tokenized and lemmatized into words.*

I want to check similarity between *word in a tweet* and all *words in the medical file*. I want to check how closest is the *word in a tweet* to any medical word.

Can the above be accomplished? Please help me out with all possible ways to accomplish the above.

Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: How about soundex search. here is an implementation on activestate  (untested) http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52213-soundex-algorithm/

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? The best stackoverflow questions are about specific problems you've encountered trying to solve a problem.

Comment: This is a very ill-defined question. Are you looking for surface similarity, distributional similarity, ...

Answer (score 1):

Since your terminology is in the medical domain, you might want to consider the use of the UMLS. UMLS::Similarity could help you find similarity between medical terms. 
http://umls-similarity.sourceforge.net

Good luck,
Ted